# Eclipse IDE for C++

Tags: c++, eclipse

So i just downloaded Eclipse kepler for C and C++
and then i tried to make a simple HelloWorld app,

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!!!" << endl; // prints Hello World!!!
    return 0;
}
```

but i got an error saying:

```
Program "g++" not found in PATH
Program "gcc" not found in PATH
Program "make" not found in PATH
Symbol 'cout' could not be resolved
Symbol 'endl' could not be resolved
Symbol 'std' could not be resolved
```

Comment: Seems like you didn't install any compiler...

Comment: Well i'm new to C++ and C don't know how

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/gdcwin/

Comment: [Code Block](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code::Blocks) is better option. It includes many compiler with it.

Comment: Try Visual Studio instead; it's free now.

Answer (score -1):

You need to right click on properties and update the paths.